# Copy 10 cells' content to Windows Clipboard and pass to another program one by one through vba

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy 10 cells into Windows Clipboard one by one so my clipboard manager software (Ditto) grab them and then I use these copied content somewhere else. But it seems that excel waits until the subroutine ends then put the last copied item into Windows Clipboard. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710435/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-a-cell-into-the-clipboard), `sendkeys "^c"` with `sleep()` and also tried `range().copy` for each individual cell to do the copy process in a `for` loop, but every time I only have the content of the last cell available in Ditto.

```
Sub copy()
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = ActiveCell.Row
For c = 1 To 10
    Cells(r, c).copy
Next c
End Sub
```

When this sub ends what I have in Ditto is the content of the last cell while if I manually copy cells one by one in Excel I will have each cell available in Ditto. I'm trying to achieve the results of manual process but do it through vba.

Comment: And what is your question exactly? To help you we would need that and a [mcve]

Comment: Each time you use `.Copy` it replaces what is in your clipboard with the new information.

Comment: yes, but ditto is running in background and grabs everything I copy to clipboard.

Comment: But is Ditto polling\monitoring of the Windows Clipboard faster than VBA's for-loop?  Put a timer in the for-loop.      `t = timer
    While timer - t < 1#
    Wend`

Comment: Another thing to test is ignoring ditto while the for-loop is iterating on the 1-second timer.  Every second, ctrl-V into MS-Word or something.  This will prove whether all the data is or isn't getting copied correctly.

Comment: @Iman it works.  I tested it with the timer controlling the loop speed.

Comment: @Jaberwocky But I couldn't. Every time macro is running I have no paste option available in Word, but I it's available in notepad, but even after pressing paste option or ctrl+V in notepad nothing is pasted. when macro ends while there is that rectangular dotted marque around the last cell, I'm able to paste and what it pasts is the content of first cell !

Comment: @Iman Don't do it in word.  The timer actually stops all MSO VBA operations (which freezes up all MSO apps), no matter the MSO app.  Use Notepad or something else free from VBA.

Comment: now I also closed ditto completely, While macro is running operations are somehow locked and I cannot paste. by finishing macro job, I'm able to paste, sometime last cell, sometime second, ... . and by canceling selection in excel I have nothing to paste

Comment: @Iman That's because of the timer.  Just remove it - it was only for testing.  The code is working correctly.  The problem is with Ditto.  I suspect it doesn't capture the copies as fast as the VBA runs.  Check the settings, and see if you can increase the rate that it checks for content.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved it :
I added a 2 seconds delay between each clipboard copy
(less than that it would not work)

Here is my code :

```
Sub DittoTest()
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
c = ActiveCell.Column

For r = 1 To 100
    If Cells(r, c).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Cells(r, c).copy
    'MsgBox "ligne " & r & " : " & Cells(r, c).Value
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Next r

MsgBox r & " ligne(s) copiée(s)"

End Sub
```